# Finding distribution from Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Assume X a random variable with a finite variance, and also that $M_{X}\left(t\right)=at+b$, what is the distribution for X.

I really have no idea where to start, I know that $at+b=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}e^{tx}P\left(X=x\right)$ so I thought that if $$P\left(X=0\right)=b\ \land\ P\left(X=\frac{ln\left(t\right)}{t}\right)=a$$ and for any other x P(X=x)=0 i get what i want, but that is only true  if a+b=1 no? and I couldn't manage to prove that, and also I don't know how to use the fact that X has finite variance. any help is welcomed :)

Comment: Is there a typo? $M_X(0)=1$ should hold for any random variable $X$, but yours only holds if $b=1$.

Comment: To start with, as AngryAvian said, you must have $b=1$, otherwise the distribution won't be normalized. Apart from that, is $X$ discrete or continuous ?

Comment: @angryavian - it gets more restrictive and $a=0$ is also forced: $E[X^2] = M''(0)=0$ so $X$ is almost surely $0$ with $M_X(t)=\mathbb E[e^{tX}]=1$

Comment: a variance of $0$ is indeed a finite variance.

Comment: @Henry In that case, the only possibility would be the Dirac distribution $f_X(x) = \delta(x)$.

Comment: @angryavian X is discrete, also there is no more information in the question, maybe there is a typo in the question? strange I guess it really has to be almost surely 0, but then why they specified that X has a finite Var

Comment: @Abzikro indeed whenever there is a moment generating function, you must have all the raw and central moments finite, including the variance, though having them finite does not guarantee a moment generating function (consider the log-normal)

Comment: @Henry Thank you! So it means that if the MGF of variable is polynomial it must be the it almost surely 0? seems pretty straight because some derivative will be 0, but I just wanna be sure.

Comment: @Abzikro which is why you do not see polynomials in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples